# Two dataframes connected by index

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, refer

I have two dataframes.

```
[2500 rows x 4 columns]
                   Kundenname              Adresse                Ort      PLZ
0          Amt Nortorfer Land        Niedernstraße 6            Nortorf  24539.0
1                Nord    GmbH         Heilbadstr. 85            Münster  24529.0
2               Vertrieb GmbH              Straße  4             Kassel  31117.0
.......


[1900 rows x 38 columns]
   0     1      2       3     4     5   ...    32    33    34    35    36    37
0  (0   118   1999   2117)  None  None  ...  None  None  None  None  None  None
1  (1   2000) None   None   None ....
....
```

The result should be like this:

```
              Kundenname          Adresse      Ort      PLZ
0     Amt Nortorfer Land  Niedernstraße 6  Nortorf  24589.0
118   Amt Nortorfer Land  Niedernstraße 6  Nortorf  24589.0
1999  Amt Nortorfer Land  Niedernstraße 6  Nortorf  24589.0
2117  Amt Nortorfer Land  Niedernstraße 6  Nortorf  24589.0

1       ......
2000    ......
```

etc.

I just did it with `df.loc[[9,118,1999,2117]]` but I need a loop or something that I don't have to type in manually.

Comment: Does the second dataframe really contain parentheses `(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When df1 is your dataframe with your address data, and df2 is your index dataframe as such:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({0:[0,1], 1:[118, 2000], 2:[1999, None], 3:[2117, None], 4:[None, None]})
```

You can rewrite your index_dataframe (df2) using melt:

```
index_values = pd.melt(df2.reset_index(), id_vars='index').set_index('index')[['value']].dropna()
```

This will give you the following result:

```
        value
index   
0       0
1       1
0       118
1       2000
0       1999
0       2117
```

You can use this to merge with your df1:

```
index_values.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True).set_index('value')
```

Result:

```
        Kundenname          Adresse         Ort     PLZ
value               
0.0     Amt Nortorfer Land  Niedernstraße 6 Nortorf 24539.0
118.0   Amt Nortorfer Land  Niedernstraße 6 Nortorf 24539.0
1999.0  Amt Nortorfer Land  Niedernstraße 6 Nortorf 24539.0
2117.0  Amt Nortorfer Land  Niedernstraße 6 Nortorf 24539.0
1.0     Nord GmbH           Heilbadstr. 85  Münster 24529.0
2000.0  Nord GmbH           Heilbadstr. 85  Münster 24529.0
```

If df2 really contains parentheses, as Mr. T asked, you should remove these first of course. Assuming all your df2-values are string, this would mean doing something like:

```
index_values.value = index_values.value.str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '').astype(float)
```